# C++ string termination not happening ? Why?

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int t;
cin>>t;
cin.ignore();
while(t--){
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    
    int i =0;
    int count =0;
    while(i<s.size()){
        if(s[i]!=' '){
            //cout<<count<<":";
            s[count++]=s[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    s[count]='\0';
    cout<<s<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
   }
```

Why in the end String is not terminating with '\0'?

For Input:

```
2
geeks  for geeks
g f g
```

your output is:

```
geeksforgeeksks
gfgg f g
```

Comment: please be more clear on what is your output and what you expected instead.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize

Comment: When modifying a `std::string` in ways that change the size you can't use the `[]` operator. `[]` lets you change the value of an existing character. It does not update the status information telling the `string` that it is shorter or longer.

Comment: This program to suppose to remove space from string.

Comment: It doesn't. It writes over the storage where the space sat. The `string` has no idea that it now contains one fewer character. The extra control information that makes `string` much more easy to use than a character array most of the time makes this use case slightly more difficult because the control information needs to be updated.

Comment: The C-style termination is happening, but C++ strings don't work like C strings. To see the effect of the C-style terminator, try `std::cout << s.c_str() << '\n';`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a character from a string, you should use `erase`.

See the [remove-erase idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is not a C-style null terminated string (but you can obtain one from it). As such, inserting a null character will not terminate it. If you want to truncate a string from the end, you can simply `resize()` it. Otherwise, if you want to remove characters, you can `erase()` them.

You say you want to remove spaces. To do that with your existing code, simply replace `s[count]='\0';` with `s.resize(count);`, eg:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    cin.ignore();
    while (t--){
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
    
        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (i < s.size()){
            if (s[i] != ' '){
                //cout<<count<<":";
                s[count++] = s[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        s.resize(count);
        cout << s << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, a better way to handle this would look more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    std::cin.ignore();
    while (t--){
        std::string s;
        std::getline(cin, s);

        std::string::size_type idx = 0;
        while ((idx = s.find(‘ ‘, idx)) != std::string::npos){
            s.erase(idx, 1);
        }

        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    std::cin.ignore();
    while (t--){
        std::string s;
        std::getline(cin, s);

        std::string::iterator iter = std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ‘ ‘);
        s.erase(iter, s.end());

        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```